# Variable size Array in Java or C#

Tags: arrays

I'm trying to be able to alter the size of an array based on a variable. I was thinking I might maybe later make it a 2D array. I don't want to use arraylist.

```
int i = 4;
int[] arr = new int[i];
```

How do you get something like this to work? It gives me error CS0236.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the int static